# jQuery: time function outputs wrong number of days

Tags: jquery, date

I need to calculate the day difference between two dates and have the problem with my code. For example, the target date is contained in an input-field (id="targetdate") and has the format **dd/mm/yyyy**:

09.02.2014

I have the following code:

```
targetdate = $('#targetdate').val();

// the format is "dd/mm/yyyy", so I need to write the following extra code:                 
var day = targetdate.substring(0,2);
var month = targetdate.substring(3,5);
var year = targetdate.substring(6,10);          

// Calculation difference of days
var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000;  // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
var endDate = new Date(year,month,day);
var today = new Date();
var diffDays = (Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - today.getTime())/(oneDay))));
```

I get wrong results with the code:

- if the enddate is today, I get "27"
- if the enddate is tomorrow, I get "28"
- if the enddate is the day after tomorrow, I get "29"

Where is the problem?

Comment: *Never* add 24*60*60*1000 to get the following/previous day! In most timezones that works great for 363 days per year, but it can create big problems when DST starts or ends!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing a `Date` instance, the "months" value starts with **zero** for January, so:

```
var endDate = new Date(year,month-1,day);
// You need to remove one -------^^
```

Also note that you should be parsing those strings, e.g.:

```
var day = parseInt(targetdate.substring(0,2), 10);
var month = parseInt(targetdate.substring(3,5), 10);
var year = parseInt(targetdate.substring(6,10), 10);
```

Comment: thanx, i made the changes you suggested, but now i get the following wrong results: if the enddate equals today, I get "1", if the enddate is tomorrow, I get "0", and if the enddate is the day after tmrw I get "1".... how can this happen?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a 1 (`enddate == today` gives you 1 instead of -1 because of `Math.abs`)

Comment: Also, `+1` on the radix in parseInt. always a bugger.

Comment: @KentMiller you need to se the time part to 0 for today